# Работа с путями до файлов

Tags: python

Допустим у меня есть такой путь в виде строки: `PycharmProjects/tests/logging/log/test.log`, Как мне его легко преобразовать средствами Python к `PycharmProjects/tests/logging/log/dumps/test.log` ?

! Название файла `test.log` переменно и может быть произвольной длины.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так, например:

```
inPath = "PycharmProjects/tests/logging/log/test.log"
head,tail = os.path.split(inPath)
outPath = os.path.join(head, "dumps", tail)
```

Документация на этот крайне полезный модуль - по ссылке https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html